# How to install CentOS 7 over Debian jessie remotely?

Tags: debian, centos

Is it possible overwrite - migrate / reinstall a server with Debian Jessie to CentOS 7 remotely?

I have only SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be rather challenging, because a single mistake will essentially lock you out of the machine. You cannot just "swap" the OS underneath your currently running, you'll have to reboot (at least once).

If you do not have (otherwise) physical access to the machine, I can only advise against this.

Here we go anyway:
I am not aware of your particular setup, but you roughly need to do the following:

1. Split the partitions: one boot partition (you should already have one), one for CentOS (the one you currently have, shrink this one) and a third one for Debian. You can use tools such as **fdisk** for this.
2. Bootstrap Debian into the empty, third partition. Have a look at **debootstrap** for this task. Don't forget to also configure networking and the SSH server in this new installation (otherwise you won't be able to log into the machine).
3. Reconfigure the bootloader (most likely GRUB on x86/x64 systems) to use the third partition for booting by default (instead of the second one)
4. Reboot. And hope your new systems start successfully and you can log into it.

As I mentioned before, this is **very risky**. If you do not have any way of recovering the machine (i.e. physical access, ILO, etc.), I highly advise against this!

Comment: I think the OP wants to install CentOS over Debian, not the other way around as per your recipe. Speaking of which, I'd rather boot into a preseeded Debian installer (with network console started automatically) instead of trying to `debootstrap` manually, and thus avoid mucking with the partitions. It's also easier to test locally, which is very important in situations where a single wrong move definitely puts you out of the game.